# How to validate API Key in AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have read quite a few articles like [this one](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248108) and it looks like currently in AWS API Gateway you cannot send API Key in query string. 
We also have few legacy clients that will need passing api-key in query string.
So i thought of two options

1>Create lambda function as `Integration Type` and validate API in key inside function handler. But i am not able to figure out how to validate it against keys in aws. Something like

```
public async Task<JObject> FunctionHandler(JObject request, ILambdaContext context)
{
      // i know how to get apikey from queryStringParameters here 
      // but how do i validate it against api keys in aws
}
```

2> Create new custom authorizer, but again not sure how do i do it.

Which would be prefered option. **I am using .NET core**. Are there any nuget packages already available?

*Please note querystring support is required and not debatable even if it is not recommended for security reason*

Answer (score 1):

You can pass security key in query param use header and pass key

```
curl -X PUT \
https://XXXX.XXXXX-api.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/PROD/XXX-microservice \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -H 'x-api-key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
 -d '{

 "initData": "HI",
 "name": "vaquar khan",
 "likes": "Java"
}'
```

> Security key validation taken care by API getaway so no lambda
>   authorizer required

If you are passing in query string

URL:

```
https://XXXX.XXXXX-api.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/PROD/XXX-microservice ?x-api-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX &uid=5
```

### Python 2.7

```
from __future__ import print_function

import boto3
import json

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event['params']['querystring']['x-api-key'])
    print(event['params']['querystring']['uid'])
```