# AWS lambda custom authorizer using .NET Core

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-net

In AWS API Gateway I am developing lambda function for custom authorizer using .NET Core. The API will receive api-key in query string and my custom authroizer will validate the key. Based on my understanding, after validation is done the lambda function needs to return [IAM policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html). The [awslab blurprint](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-lambda-authorizer-blueprints) does not have any example for .NET core. The only example i found so far is [GrandmasRecipes](https://github.com/RecursiveLoop/GrandmasRecipes) that is using JWT Token.

I would like to know what `IAM` policy the lambda function needs to return and are there any corresponding .NET Core classes for request and response?

**Update 1**
So below is my code for custom lambda authorizer. However i would like know:

1> What should be `PrincipalID`. Currently i am just setting it to `User`

2>`CheckAuthorization` method gets all the keys from `aws` and only check the existence by comparing the key from the request. It should also check the `Usage Plans` and make sure the key from the request is configured in `Usage Plans`

3>The role that this Authorizer is executing under is attached to `AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator` policy so that it can get API Keys, whats the minimum policy do i need for this role to validate api-key?

4>Is there any in-built method in `AWSSDK` to do validate api-key correctly?

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
namespace ApikeyAuthorizer
{
    public class Function
    {
        public async Task<APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequest authEvent, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            var key = authEvent.QueryStringParameters["key"];
            bool authorized = await CheckAuthorization(key);

            var authPolicy = new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse();
            authPolicy.PrincipalID = "user";
            authPolicy.PolicyDocument = new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy();
            authPolicy.PolicyDocument.Version = "2012-10-17";
            authPolicy.PolicyDocument.Statement = new List<APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy.IAMPolicyStatement>();
            if (authorized)
            {
                var statement = new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy.IAMPolicyStatement();
                statement.Action = new HashSet<string>(new string[] { "execute-api:Invoke" });
                statement.Effect = "Allow";
                statement.Resource = new HashSet<string>(new string[] { "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:xxxxx:*/*/GET/*" });
                authPolicy.UsageIdentifierKey = key;
                authPolicy.PolicyDocument.Statement.Add(statement);
            }
            else
            {
                var statement = new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy.IAMPolicyStatement();
                statement.Action = new HashSet<string>(new string[] { "execute-api:Invoke" });
                statement.Effect = "Deny";
                statement.Resource = new HashSet<string>(new string[] { "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:xxxxx:*/*/GET/*" });
                authPolicy.PolicyDocument.Statement.Add(statement);
            }

            return authPolicy;
        }

        public async Task<bool> CheckAuthorization(string key)
        {            
            Amazon.APIGateway.AmazonAPIGatewayClient client = new Amazon.APIGateway.AmazonAPIGatewayClient();
            var response = await client.GetApiKeysAsync(new Amazon.APIGateway.Model.GetApiKeysRequest()
            {
                IncludeValues = true
            });           

            foreach (var apiKey in response.Items)
            {               
                if (apiKey.Value == key)
                {             
                    return true;
                }
            }           
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a Lambda Authorizer to validate API Key neither it should be used for authorisation. You can do following to configure API key validation in API Gateway.

1. In you API **Resources** section, set **API Key Required** true for the methods where you want to enable it
2. Go to **API Keys** section, select **Create API key** from **Actions** dropdown and create a key
3. Go to **Usage Plans** section and create a new usage plan.
4. After you've created a usage plan click on it and then click **API Keys** tab. Here click **Add API Key to Usage Plan** and add the key you created in step # 2
5. Now click on **Details** tab then click **Add API Stage**. Select your API and stage that you want to restrict with API Key.

Your API methods are now required an x-api-key HTTP header where you've enabled it. When you request API endpoint make sure you add `x-api-key` header with same value you have created in step 2 above. If you don't add this header or put a wrong value you will get 403 Forbidden error.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -X PUT \
https://XXXX.XXXXX-api.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/PROD/XXX-microservice \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -H 'x-api-key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \
 -d '{

 "initData": "HI",
 "name": "vaquar khan",
 "likes": "Java"
}'
```

> Security key validation taken care by API getaway so no lambda
>   authorizer required

Please dont create duplicate question just update old queston ,I have answred in your question here : 
- [How to validate API Key in AWS Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014737/how-to-validate-api-key-in-aws-lambda-function/54015760#54015760)